# findViewById not working in static function

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I found error in `findViewById` in static function.

my function is--

```
public static void onYearSelect() {

    Spinner yearSelector;
    String yearName;
    yearSelector = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.year_submit);
    yearName = yearSelector.getSelectedItem().toString();

}
```

is there any way to solve this error!

**can i store value of Spinner in yearName as String**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You need to add view inside function as parameter.

```
public static void onYearSelect(View view) {

    Spinner yearSelector;
    yearSelector = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.year_submit);
    yearName = yearSelector.getSelectedItem().toString();

}
```

`The view which contains your layout data`.

> When you call that function add `onYearSelect(rootView)` here `rootView` have the layout view.

**EDIT 1:**

> What is View here ?

`A View in Android is a widget that displays something. Buttons, listviews, imageviews, etc. are all subclasses of View. When you say "change view" I assume you mean change the layout by using setContentView(). This usually only needs to be done once per activity. An Activity is basically what you are referring to as a screen.`

You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

Answer (score 0):

Set setOnItemSelectedListener on spinner object and inside onItemSelected() you can set value of yearName. Like below,

```
yearSelector.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
 String yearName = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // your code here
}});
```